# iPhone : Inapp purchase : paymentWithProduct:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, in-app-purchase

I am trying inapp purchase.

I am unable to implement following method :

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:`SKProduct`];
```

But here I dont know from where I will get this `SKProduct`'s object or which parameter I have to pass here ?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you looked at the developer reference information? That should explain it all.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have a valid product registered on itunesconnect, and you know the product's identifier, you could do something like this:

```
SKMutablePayment *payment = [[[SKMutablePayment alloc] init] autorelease];
payment.productIdentifier = @"myvalidproductidentifier";
payment.quantity = <quantity>;
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Observe that you will need a valid product identifier otherwise the payment queue will return an error, usually: *"Cannot connect to iTunes store"*.

Comment: Was it worked for you ? as `productIdentifier` is read only property !

Comment: This works for me, productIdentifier is readwrite if you use the Mutable payment class.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using MKStoreKit by [Mugunth Kumar](http://mugunthkumar.com)

It will massively simplify your code base and includes clear instructions for handling all type of products (consumables etc)